# Establing the direction of $\vec F = F_{\theta}\hat \theta$ given inital conditions in an exercise

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, centripetal-force

I'm trying to test myself on whether my knowledge of polar coordinates and angular motion is correct in the following scenario:

[image]

For the first part (a), I've provided a sketch to confirm I know what's going on. It may not be necessary, but I've decided to attach it anyway:

[image]

Since the child is moving about in uniform circular motion, at least in our initial condition, the following is true:

$$F_{net} = F_x = m v^2/r$$

For the second part, I've never actually done something like this before, admittedly, something so simple as to just writing down the position vector for a child in the $x, y$ plane. But, my view is that it should just simply be:

$$\vec r = r_0 \hat r$$

Now, for the actual thing I'm asking about.

- The coordinates for $x = R$ and $y = 0$ in cylindrical Polar coordinates, that means the point is at $\theta = 0$ or $\theta = \pi$ since $y = 0$ and $x = R$ which insists the only two coordinates I can have for this scenario is $(R,0)$ or $(R, \pi)$, although, given the graphic I believe the convention is $+x$ is to the right of the page, so it should be $(R, 0)$.
- To sketch the roundabout indicating the point of contact of the force and direction of the force, the direction of the force, whether it's going down the page or up the page is unaware to me. I see no implication other than $F = F_{\theta} \hat \theta$ which may imply that the force is going up the page, since $\dot \theta$ is counter-clockwise, which would imply the convention for $\hat \theta$ should be a unit vector pointing perpendicular to $\hat r$ but also along $+y$ at $(R,0)$, since otherwise the object wouldn't be rotating the way it is, if that makes any sense, thus the graphic I drew is:

[image]

Is my interpretation right? And if not, why?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right, we define the polar coordinate the way you did which is the $\hat r$ is along the line between the origin and your point, and $\hat \theta$ is defined to be along the "normal" way to measure angles, which is counter-clockwise. So yes, your drawing is good. However, I'd like to say that there is an error in the question. When we ask about a point given in *cylindrical polar coordinate* we want something of the form $(r,\theta,z)$ which is not what is asked. In this question, the question should be give your answer in *polar coordinate* which is of the form $(r,\theta)$.

Comment: Right, I had a feeling the cylindrical polar coordinate bit was odd, but the question says "in cylindricall Polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$ instead of $(r,\theta, z)$, so I just elected to do it that way. Also, is my intuition correct on the direction of the force?

Comment: Yes because here $F=F_\theta \hat\theta$. So it is in the "usual" way to measure angles. By "usual" I really mean starting from the positive $x$ axis then going counter clockwise.